# Javascript class static methods memory consumption

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm aware that a prototype is defined once and is common for all object instances, but each is binded to the context of the new instance created.I'm also aware that it saves memory in comparison to a method defined with `this` inside the constructor:

```
function Person(name) {

    this.name = name;

    // each instance will have it's own talk method
    // so 500 * person instances = 500 * this.talk in memory
    this.talk = function(str) {
        console.log(this.name,"said",str);
    };

}

// 500 * person instances = 1 instance of talk2 in memory
Person.prototype.talk2 = function(str) {

    console.log(this.name,"said",str);

};
```

However I'm not sure about static methods and memory consumption.

```
// 500 * person instances = x * talk3 in memory ?
Person.talk3 = function(str) {

    // code

};
```

Are they like prototypes or not?

Comment: *"...but each is binded to the context of the new instance created"* Um, not really, no. The object is bound to the prototype, not the other way around.

Comment: "Binding" is established *at call time* in Javascript, not when the instance is created. Until then the method is just a property of an object (the prototype), which all instances share.

Comment: Yes, I might have expressed my thoughts the wrong way what I meant is what you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many instances of `Person` you create, there is only one `Person.talk3` function.

---

Side note: Your comments about `talk` and `talk2` are both correct in terms of how many function *objects* are created. A modern JavaScript engine may well reuse the *code* from `talk` in each of the 500 function objects created for it (which could be relevant if there's a lot of code), but that's an implementation/optimization detail.

Comment: @Syd: I'm not sure all modern ones don't, when it's reasonable/useful to do so. Even Microsoft's JavaScript engine is pretty darned good these days. :-)

Comment: Yeap thing have evolved :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Having there is one copy of the function, are the local variables allocated in stack when calling this single function in multiple instances ?

Comment: @CharlieH - Yes. Locals are always on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

They are only like prototypes in the sense that they are allocated once. Apart from that, they are **not** shared or made available on instances in any way.

Also, a "static" method like `Person.talk3` in your example will have the `Person` function itself as the context object ("`this`") when called. Unless you actually refer to `this` in the static method, `Person.talk3` will be exactly the same as a regular function, e.g. `function personTalk () {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = new Person;
p.talk3(); // TypeError
```

`talk3` does not exist on an instance of `Person`. It only exists as a property of the constructor function, *once*.