# Javascript tree traversal function error

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I am getting my hands around the javascript environment. I tried implementing a function which does the inorder traversal of a tree, however I ran into an error. Below is my code.

I created a `Node` class which defines the properties of the node object.
In my `Tree` class the constructor defines the root property. When I call the Inorder function with the root as argument, the compiler throws an error on the line `-->Inorder(root.left)` showing `-- Inorder is not defined--`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Tree {


    constructor(root) {

        this.root = root;
    }


    Inorder(root) {

        if (root == null) {
            return;

        }

        Inorder(root.left);
        console.log(root.data);
        Inorder(root.right);


    }

}


class Node {

    constructor(data) {

        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;

    }

}


const obj = new Node(5);
obj.left = new Node(10);
obj.right = new Node(15);
obj.left.left = new Node(16);
obj.right.right = new Node(17);


const tree = new Tree(obj);
console.log(tree.root.data);
tree.Inorder(tree.root);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to the Inorder method needs to be run on the instance, or on the class, since it only exists as an instance method of the class Tree. See the example:

```
class Tree {
    constructor(root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    Inorder(root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        // HERE:
        this.Inorder(root.left);

        console.log(root.data);

        // And HERE:
        this.Inorder(root.right);
    }
}


class Node {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

const obj = new Node(5);
obj.left = new Node(10);
obj.right = new Node(15);
obj.left.left = new Node(16);
obj.right.right = new Node(17);


const tree = new Tree(obj);
console.log(tree.root.data);
tree.Inorder(tree.root);
```

**edited:** a static method makes no sense for what you need, so I took that out of the answer

**edit 2:** add a snippet showing an optimization for the recursive function.

Note that now, on the recursion part, the method can be static since it doesn't need to know about instance data. It can run from a root node independently of the tree that called it.

This would help optimizing memory use if you would use lots of instances, since the method is defined only on the `Tree` class itself.

```js
class Tree {
  constructor(root) {
    this.root = root;
  }

  // Inorder method doesn't need a root argument now
  // It uses instance's own root
  Inorder() {
    // Fire up the recursion
    Tree._Inorder(this.root);
  }

  // Private part for the Inorder method's recursion
  // It can be static since it will receive the root 
  // for each iteration
  static _Inorder(root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return;
    }

    Tree._Inorder(root.left);

    console.log(root.data);

    Tree._Inorder(root.right);
  }
}


class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

const obj = new Node(5);
obj.left = new Node(10);
obj.right = new Node(15);
obj.left.left = new Node(16);
obj.right.right = new Node(17);

const tree = new Tree(obj);
console.log("Tree created with root:", tree.root.data);

// Now we can call the inorder list for the tree 
// without explicitely specifying the root node
tree.Inorder();
```

Comment: realised my mistake. so i am guessing 'this' in this case refers to the 'tree' object since it is the object calling the function inorder?

Comment: @batman007 you are correct, non-static methods defined inside a class will execute in the context of the instance calling them. So when you call `tree.Inorder(tree.root)` on the last line, you are calling the method on the `tree` instance. This means you don't really need to supply a root, since it will be the current tree's root. Because the method is recursive, you could then split it into the public part you already have, and a private part for the recursion, that actually accepts a root element as argument. I could extend the answer with the actual code if it helps ;)

Comment: can you please add a code snippet for further reference. that would be really helpful.

Comment: Added the customization, hope it is useful!

Comment: I was playing with it to actually build the tree. Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/oscar_dr/69kd7s3r/

Comment: i am not an expert on memory optimization but from what i can see in the above code , instead of having a recursion tree created for each separate instance, a common memory is being used with the help of static methods?correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: @batman007 that's right. The method `_Inorder` belongs to the class `Tree`, not to any particular _instance_ of `Tree`. In javascript this really doesn't make much of a difference in terms of memory, though, since the way it handles instance methods is through the object's _prototype_, where they are defined. When an instance method is called, the _prototype_ method is actually called, with the context for `this` set to the caller instance. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898166/javascript-class-static-methods-memory-consumption

Answer (score 2):

In the Inorder function in you Tree class refer to inner Inorder calls with "this" in front. For example: `this.Inorder(left);`